# better vscode yaml group highlight possible?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, highlight

Is it possible to highlight the currently selected group/object/list in vs code?[image]

As you can see there is a "basic highlighting" the grey vertical line highlight. But I would like to use a (just a bit) lighter dark grey as background colour for all affected lines. Instead of just a simple grey vertical line.

Only for YAML files though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the indent guide below `selector` is already highlighted to show its children.

You can try [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=byi8220.indented-block-highlighting) which highlights other items on the same indentation depth.